# How to refactor route endpoints into ORM structure?

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, api, orm

I'm not even sure exactly what constitutes an endpoint and how to turn it into ORM. I'm new to Angular, but from my understanding an endpoint is when you get data from a server, be it an online API or a database query using SQL.
From my research, ORM basically makes the code more high level and gets rid of the need for SQL, but how do you do it? And what if there is no SQL, and it's a request to an online API using a URL?

For clarification, I am working on a website that uses Angular. There is a database, an API, and a UI, and the API pulls data from online APIs and from the database. So my question is about how to refactor both types of endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

ORM is a way to work with objects and let a framework take care of converting the object into a way required for the DB or data from DB to objects. UI has nothing to do with it. It is only a concern of the data layer or data tier of your backend. May be we can go on and say that even the controller part or others of your backend need not be aware of the ORM.

So the abstraction you have is

1. Irrespective of type of DB you talk in terms of your Model classes
2. Whether the data comes from DB or from another online API call by backend, finally it will also be a model object and can be sent to UI

The UI layer need not or should not know how your backend is getting the details that is required for UI. so the structure should be based more on Common sense, domain, your requirements etc and not on how backend acquires data.

And the same applies to API endpoints too. Create them in a meaningful way for your application. Example:

```
// this might be some of the endpoints required for a e commerce site

/product/recommendations      // returns recommended products for a user
/product/categories           // returns categories of products
/user/getCartItems            // returns cart items of user
/orders/cancel                // cancel a order
```

see how the api endpoints are completly unaware of how backend handles / retreives the data